# Writing a binary file to the Xilinx Fpga QSPI at a specific address

Tags: memory

I'm very new to the FPGA AND vhdl world. I have a binary file that contains some information and I want to put it into the Flash QSPI of the Xilinx nexys video board and then read it from my main program to cast into the UART.

So I wonder if there is some application that can take my file and the address where I want my file to be stored and then do the job.

Can Vivado or Vitis do this?

Comment: You will have to write the program yourself.

Answer (score 0):

From the Nexys video board page I found some relevant resources [here](https://digilent.com/reference/programmable-logic/nexys-video/reference-manual).  See section "2.2. Quad-SPI Programming" for details on how to load the flash with data.

> The [Nexys Video Programming Guide](https://digilent.com/reference/learn/programmable-logic/tutorials/nexys-video-programming-guide/start) available on the Nexys Video
> Resource Center walks through the process of programming the Quad-SPI
> flash from Vivado.

Your Vivado project should initialize BRAM with a local file.  See [here](https://docs.xilinx.com/v/u/2018.3-English/ug901-vivado-synthesis) for reference code.

**Initializing Block RAM From an External Data File (Verilog)**

**Filename: rams_init_file.v**

```
// Initializing Block RAM from external data file
// Binary data
// File: rams_init_file.v 
module rams_init_file (clk, we, addr, din, dout);
input clk;
input we;
input [5:0] addr;
input [31:0] din;
output [31:0] dout;
reg [31:0] ram [0:63];
reg [31:0] dout;
initial begin
$readmemb("rams_init_file.data",ram);
end
always @(posedge clk)
begin
 if (we)
 ram[addr] <= din;
 dout <= ram[addr];
end endmodule
```

You also need to have a UART controller interacting with the TX/RX pins as shown in the section "USB UART Bridge (Serial Port)":

> The Nexys Video includes an FTDI FT232R USB-UART bridge (attached to
> connector J13) that lets you use PC applications to communicate with
> the board using standard Windows COM port commands. Free USB-COM port
> drivers, available from Windows Update or [www.ftdichip.com](http://www.ftdichip.com) under the
> “Virtual Com Port” or VCP heading, convert USB packets to UART/serial
> port data. Serial port data is exchanged with the FPGA using a
> two-wire serial port (TXD/RXD) with no handshake signals. After the
> drivers are installed, I/O commands can be used from the PC directed
> to the COM port to produce serial data traffic on the V18 and AA19
> FPGA pins.

To save time, Nexys has provided you an entire project located [here](https://github.com/Digilent/Nexys-Video-GPIO).  Just modify the UART to read from the BRAM and transmit data when required.

Comment: Please quote the details here